# Show that $F(x,y)=2^x(2y+1)$ is onto from $\mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Tags: functions

Here is the problem:

Let $C$ be the set of nonnegative integers. Let $A=C\times C$ and $B=C$.
Let $F(x,y)=2^x(2y+1)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in C.

How do I show whether $F$ is a function from $A$ onto $B$?

Comment: By using the definition of "onto" more or less directly.

Comment: Actually the function is not "onto". $F(x,y)$ cannot take value $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not onto because it can't take value zero. However if you  take $B=C- \{ 0 \}$, then it is onto. Simply observe that, by putting $x=0$, you can get all odd positive integers. For any even positive integer, divide it by maximum possible power of 2. Then you'll left with odd integer. Choose your $y$ accordingly. For example, if you want to get 12, $\frac{12}{2^2}=3.$ So, take $x= 2$ and $y= 1$.